# Design for amplifier make/model settings database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

As a personal project, I essentially want to create a web application that allows users to submit amplifier settings for specific tones, which will render images and create an archive of guitar tones for specific amps.

I know that I first should design a database to support this web application.  After reading about [relational databases and normalization](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&ved=0CE4QFjAG&url=http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/&ei=cx-6UqSkIKeayQGq8oCYCA&usg=AFQjCNHp_sW6SB6GxDNh7jf2k1KZn2HN5A&sig2=IHgTbAzZFMfEk1LCXXhybw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc), I have started to draft a database, but I've confused myself in the process.

So far, I've created the following tables:

**tbl_Makes** (list of amplifier brands):

[image]

**tbl_Models** (list of amplifier models, linked to their brand by the MakeID field):

[image]

But I am at a bit of a loss on how to design the remaining table(s).  I assume I will need a **tbl_Settings** table which contains both MakeID, and ModelID as foreign keys, but also some sort of column(s) to hold the amplifier settings.  The issue I'm currently facing is that most amplifiers have different settings, so I'm not sure how I'd handle that.  Would I need an additional table for each amplifier model to hold its specific settings?

Any suggestions?  Is my current database design ok, or does it need to be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be breaking it down too far.  A table with Make and Model may be good enough.  However with your current design, you would make the MakeID a Foreign Key to the Make table's Primary Key (ID).

Then you'd have an "settings" table which has a ModelID, attribute, and value - since each AMP may have different attributes.  You may want to have an attribute table and use attributeID if you want to control the attribute types (with a PK and FK relationship).

Oh, and for the love of God, please don't prefix tables with `tbl_`

Comment: I had a feeling I was breaking it down too far.  Thanks for your insight! I was curious about prefixing tables with `tbl_`, because some tables and views I've been working with have been prefixed with `tbl_` and `vw_`.  Definitely will remove those!

Comment: As a DBA, I've seen tables prefixed with `tbl_`, `zzz_`, and something that resembles [Hungarian_notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (ord_orderheader).  Fewer things make people say, "WTH?"  The developer should know if he's reading / writing from a view or table as it should be abstracted away in the DAL.

Comment: One more thing, you're not doing anything wrong by breaking it down "too far".  It's just that you'll have to do a lot of JOINs to get the values for your presentation layer.